# How To Catch Errors When Adding a Field With Knex.JS

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

We're using knex.js to generate and execute SQL. We're having trouble trapping errors when adding fields to an existing table and the [documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Schema) does not cover this specific use-case. Attempting to add a duplicate field does return an error in the console (VSCODE), but none of standard events are called on an error so we can't trap it in code. Here's the code:

```
knex.schema.table(tableName, function(table) {

    table.string('test').catch(function(e) {
        callback(e)
    });

}).then(function(e) {
    callback(e);
}).catch(function(e) {
    callback(e);
})
```

This is returned in the VSCODE console:

```
{ [TypeError: table.string(...).catch is not a function] 'error@context': { accessToken: undefined } }
```

However, none of the callbacks are called. How can we check for errors when adding fields?

**UPDATE #1** This code will call the callback, but obviously without any error information. And, the same error appears in the console regardless:

```
table.string('test').catch(
    callback(null, Lib.returnEvent(false))
);
```

**UPDATE #2** No callbacks are called with the following code:

```
knex.schema.table(tableName, function(table) {
    table.string('ddd');
}).then(function(e) {
    callback(e);
}).catch(function(e) {
    callback(e);
})
```

**UPDATE #3** In this example the first callback is called, but the function hangs on subsequent calls:

```
knex.schema.table(tableName, function(table) {
    table.string('ddd');
    callback(true);
}).then(function(e) {
    callback(true, e);
}).catch(function(e) {
    callback(false, e);
})
```

Comment: Your error is about `table.string('test')` cause table.string('test') does not return a promise object.
Can you catch the error in the later added catch if you remove that catch?

Comment: No. Just calling table.string('test') will add the field initially. But there appears to be no error  thrown if it's a duplicate. Neither the outer 'then' nor 'catch' are called on success or failure. However, I do get a 'ER_DUP_FIELDNAME' message in the console window.

Comment: A new code sample is provided above. Even if I add a callback immediately after the table.string() call the second call to this function always hangs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by switching to the Knex callback approach rather than using the promises approach. This code works consistently:

```
knex.schema.table(tableName, function(table) {

    table.string(tableFieldname);

}).asCallback(function(err) {

    if (err) {
       callback(false, err);
    } else {
       callback(true);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
return knex('users')
        .insert({
          username: req.body.username,
          password: hash,
        })
        .returning('*')
        .bind(console)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
```